# ¿Como acceder a las propiedades de una instancia?

Tags: php, poo

lamento las molestias pero he empezado a aprender cómo crear objetos en PHP, sin embargo no me deja acceder a las propiedades mediante "->".

Este es mi código, me gustaría que en la pantalla se aparecieran las ruedas que tiene $Coche1:

```
class Coche{

  public $ruedas;
  public $color;

  function Prueba(){
    $this->color="azul";
    $this->ruedas=5;
 
  }
 }

 $Coche1=new Coche;

 echo $Coche1->ruedas;
```

Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para conseguir lo que deseas tienes dos formas:

1. Mediante el método [__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php), que se carga al inicializar la clase, de este modo:

```
class Coche
{
  public $ruedas;
  public $color;

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->color  = "azul";
    $this->ruedas = 5;
  }
}

$Coche1 = new Coche();

echo $Coche1->ruedas;
```

2. Llamando al método Prueba() antes de preguntarle las ruedas, así:

```php
class Coche
{
  public $ruedas;
  public $color;

  function Prueba()
  {
    $this->color  = "azul";
    $this->ruedas = 5;
  }
}

$Coche1 = new Coche();
$Coche1->Prueba();
echo $Coche1->ruedas;
```

Ya nos diras si te funcionan.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Sí me ha funcionado.